# What does this sentence regarding the Riemannian metric mean?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am slowly working through a text on ordinary differential equations and I don't understand what this particular exercise is even asking of me.

The exercise says to determine the geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the cylinder with unit radius with respect to the Riemannian metric obtained by restricting the usual dot product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My problem is that I do not know what it means to be "respect to the Riemannian metric obtained by restricting the usual dot product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have tried to read about the Riemannian metric assuming that there is just a simple distance function I would need to write down my Langrangian but I am mostly finding a lot of results about Riemannian manifolds using notation far more complex than anything I've been previously introduced to. Otherwise I've tried looking through several books on calculus of variations, but I cannot find anyone else using this kind of language.

I get the impression that all this language is in differential geometry, which I have never studied before so I am a little confused why this is part of a short section in the middle of a differential equations book.

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: C. Chicone. Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications. Springer-Verlag, New York 1999.


I was originally using a book by Gerald Teschl, but it wasn't as detailed as I would have liked.

Comment: Are Chicone's explanations on page 71 and 72 not clear?

Comment: It just means that the notion of distance on that particular cylinder is the same as the ambient space it sits in. So if you have a curve on the cylinder and you want to measure its length, you just measure it as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Geodesics are solutions to PDEs, and the PDE itself depends on the choice of metric. Actually, the term 'metric' in Riemannian metric is shorthand for metric tensor.

Comment: @Passing by:  geodesics are solutions of *ODEs* of the form ${\ddot x}^i + \Gamma_{jk}^i \dot x^j \dot x^k= 0$, where the $\Gamma_{jk}^i$ depend on the metric tensor.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis: ODE, PDE, potato, potatoe ;). My bad, yes ODEs, not PDEs, sorry.

Comment: @PassingBy:  tomato, tomatoe ;).  Enjoyed the "poetry" on your user page.  Watch out for the riff-raff!  Cheers!

Comment: @prometheus Thank you, that explanation helps a lot. I reread page 71-72 several times, but from the word tangent bundle forward, I really struggle with both the definitions and the intuition. (I have very little in the way of completed courses, but I read a lot of books and random stackexchange posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C \subset \mathbb R^3$ denote the cylinder with unit radius and infinite length. We choose the parametrization

$$f: [0, 2 \pi] \times  \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R^3, f(\phi,z) = \begin {array}{1} (cos \ \phi,sin \ \phi, z) \end {array}.$$

The Euclidean metric $< , >$ on $\mathbb R^3$ induces a metric on $C$. Referring to the given parametrization its metric tensor is

$$g =\begin{pmatrix} <f_\phi, f_\phi> <f_\phi, f_z>\\ <f_z,f_{\phi}> <f_z,f_z>  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}1 \ 0\\0 \ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Because the metric tensor is constant all Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{j,k}$ vanish. The two differential equations for the parameters of a geodesic reduce to

$$\frac {d^2 \phi}{dt^2} = 0, \frac {d^2 z}{dt^2} = 0$$

with the solutions
$\phi(t) = \phi_0 + \phi_1 t, z(t) = z_0+z_1t.$

**Note.** When rolling the cylinder $C$ onto the plane $\mathbb R^2$ the geodesics become straight lines in the plane.